# How does one transfer CUDA constant memory in tensorflow's C++ API

Tags: tensorflow

Say I have a CUDA GPU kernel for a custom tensorlfow op that uses constant memory:

```cc
__constant__ int cdata[100];

__global__ void frobulate(float * data)
{
   int i = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
   float value = data[i];

   for(int j=0; j < 100; ++j) {
      value += cdata[i];
   }
}
```

Then, when implementing the `Compute` method in my `Frobulate` custom op

```cc
class Frobulate : public tensorflow::OpKernel
{
public:
    void Compute(OpKernelContext * context) override
    {
        ...
        // Get the current device
        const Device & device = context->eigen_device<Eigen::GpuDevice>();

        // Local, mutating version of constant data.
        // For illustration purposes only
        int local_data[100];
        // Reason about our local shape
        TensorShape local_shape(100);
        // Create a pointer to hold allocated output
        Tensor * pinned_ary_ptr = nullptr;

        // Allocate memory for the complex_phase,
        // I don't think allocate_output is correct here...
        // but we need pinned host memory for an async transfer
        OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_output(
          0, local_shape, &pinned_ary_ptr));

        for(int i=0; i<100; ++i)
           { pinned_ary_ptr[i] = local_data[i]; }

        // Get the symbol address of cdata and enqueue an
        // async transfer on the device's stream
        int * d_cdata_ptr;
        cudaGetSymbolAddress((void **)&d_cdata_ptr, &cdata);
        cudaMemcpyAsync(d_cdata_ptr, pinned_ary_ptr, sizeof(int)*100,
           cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, device.stream());

        // Call the kernel
        frobulate<<<grid, blocks, 0, device.stream()>>>(data);
    }
};
```

1. Is this the right way to go about doing things? i.e. Ideally it would be good to make cdata an `Input` or `Attr` in my `REGISTER_OP`, but I don't think this will link up to the constant data correctly. I think the `cudaGetSymbolAddress` is necessary...
2. Is it safe? i.e.  Will I interfere with tensorflow's GPU Stream Executor by enqueueing my own cuda commands and memcpys on the supplied stream?
3. Is context->allocate_output the correct method to call to get some pinned memory? Looking in the tensorflow codebase suggests that there are temp and scratch allocators, but I don't know if they're exposed to the user...

**Edit 1:** Does this allocate pinned memory? (memory usually allocated with cudaHostAlloc, whose pages are pinned for DMA transfers to the GPU, i.e. they're prevented from being swapped out by the OS).

```cc
tensorflow::AllocatorAttributes pinned_allocator;
pinned_allocator.set_on_host(true);
pinned_allocator.set_gpu_compatible(true);

// Allocate memory for the constant data
OP_REQUIRES_OK(context, context->allocate_temp(
DT_UINT8, cdata_shape, &cdata_tensor,
pinned_allocator));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes the cudaGetSymbolAddress is necessary. Constant memory is specific to the kernel and should not
2. It should not. Just make sure that the sequence of operations in your stream execution are in the right order and synced up properly.
3. Yes output is the memory that the kernel will write as the result of the operation. the scratch memory is mainly used for memory that you need just for a single operation of the kernel. Some cudnn kernels like the convolutions one, use it. See `tensorflow/kernels/conv_ops.cc`

Comment: I started testing this today. Within a GPU op I'm guessing **allocate_temp**  allocates GPU memory since attempting to access it generates a segfault. I've experimented with specifying an allocator in the **allocate_temp** call. e.g.

        tensorflow::AllocatorAttributes pinned_allocator;
        pinned_allocator.set_on_host(true);
        pinned_allocator.set_gpu_compatible(true);

This allocates CPU memory (I can access the resulting pointer), but I don't think its pinned as changing values on the CPU and async copying to the GPU doesn't seem to reflect in the CUDA kernel...

Comment: Got it working in conjunction with AllocatorAttribute, the cudaGetSymbolAddress(..., **&cdata**); should have been cudaGetSymbolAddress(..., **cdata**);